# Adding 2 cooling fans to an amplifier circuit board

Tags: power-supply, power

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI6q5d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'd like to add (2) 5v .41A cooling fans to this Vox bass amp.  What Resistor/capacitor combo (R3/C4) would be best?

Comment: There is no combination of R3/C4 which will work in that configuration. The rest of your circuit is also implausible as drawn unless the +26V & +18V are only intended to provide a few mA into a constant load.

Comment: You would have to take exactly 20mA from the 26V rail and the current from the 18V and 5V would have to be 12mA. You would also need another tap on the transformer secondary. Don't do it like that.

Comment: Ok then.  I'll add a noisier 115v fan instead and leave the old board alone.  Thanks for you input.

Comment: Your circuit is a dead short of the secondary of that transformer!

Answer (score 5):

You need to investigate Voltage Regulators (LM78xx-type, but suitable for 40V or more input) and/or Buck Converters. And also use a bridge rectifier, since you now have a magic ground that's connected to nothing. The electrons can't read your mind about where you want them to go, so they won't go.

Series resistors are the worst possible method to make a stable and reliable voltage for anything that hasn't got the most stable current consumption imaginable. Audio circuits do not qualify for stable power needs.